# Encode Perl's Data::Dumper to JSON

Tags: arrays, json, perl

I have a Perl Data::Dumper file (data.txt) with two arrays that i need to convert into JSON.

Here's what looks like my data.txt:

```
$stats = {
  'oldtime' => '04',
  'parsedlines' => 8,
  'day_lines' => [
    undef,
    8
  ],
  'actions' => {
    'microbe' => 1
  },
  'lastnick' => 'Sky',
  'words' => {
    'Sky' => 1,
    'microbe' => 9
  },
  'times' => {
    '04' => 8
  },
  'totallines' => 8,
  'word_times' => {
    'microbe' => [
      9
    ],
    'Sky' => [
      1
    ]
  },
  'lastvisited' => {
    'microbe' => 1,
    'Parts:' => 1,
    'Sky' => 1
  },
  'line_times' => {
    'microbe' => [
      3
    ],
    'Sky' => [
      1
    ]
  },
  'lengths' => {
    'microbe' => 36,
    'Sky' => 11
  },
  'lastnormal' => '[04:35:01] <Sky> ;algkagkaga
',
  'day_times' => [
    undef,
    [
      8,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ]
  ],
  'days' => 1,
  'joins' => {
    'microbe' => 1,
    'Sky' => 1
  },
  'monocount' => 0,
  'lines' => {
    'Sky' => 1,
    'microbe' => 3
  }
};
$lines = {
  'actionlines' => {
    'microbe' => [
      '[04:33:53] * microbe is doing just a test
'
    ]
  },
  'sayings' => {
    'Sky' => [
      ';algkagkaga'
    ],
    'microbe' => [
      'Hello'
    ]
  }
};
```

So as you can see, there is 2 arrays: $stats and $lines.
I want to convert them in JSON.
Someone on here (Borodin) came with a working solution, but it output only the second array ($lines).  Here's his solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings qw/ all FATAL /;

use JSON;

print encode_json( do 'data.txt' or die $! ), "\n";
```

But here's what it output:

```
{

    "actionlines":{
        "microbe":[
            "[04:33:53] * microbe is doing just a test\n"
        ]
    },
    "sayings":{
        "microbe":[
            "Hello"
        ],
        "Sky":[
            ";algkagkaga"
        ]
    }

}
```

So it output only $lines array... Any idea of what i can do to have it working ?

Comment: Your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35690380/use-a-perls-datadumper-format-array-in-php) stated very clearly that your data file had only a single array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have two arrays. You have two hashes.

Your code calls `do` and passes its return value as the only argument of `encode_json()`. From the [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html):

> If the file is successfully compiled, do returns the value of the last expression evaluated.

What that means is you're passing the value of the last expression in your `data.txt` file as the argument to `encode_json()`. That value is the hash that was assigned to `$lines`.

Possible solutions:

1. Combine the two hashes into a single array of hashes when generating data.txt.
2. Execute the `data.txt` file prior to the `encode_json()` call, ignoring its return value. Then, combine the two variables into an anonymous array by referencing them by package-qualified name. Because their declarations were not preceded by `my`, and they were declared inside the `main` package implicitly, the package will be `main`. Here's how it would look:

---

```
require('data.txt');
print encode_json([$main::stats,$main::lines]), "\n";
```

Comment: `require` is for files with a `package` statement. The OP's use of `do` was more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

To access the hash references in your data file separately, you need to *declare* them using `our` before executing the `do`

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use JSON;

our ( $stats, $lines );

do 'data.txt' or die $!;

print encode_json( $stats ), "\n";
print encode_json( $lines ), "\n";
```

#### output

```
{"day_times":[null,[8,0,0,0]],"actions":{"microbe":1},"lines":{"microbe":3,"Sky":1},"days":1,"lastnick":"Sky","oldtime":"04","words":{"Sky":1,"microbe":9},"lastnormal":"[04:35:01] <Sky> ;algkagkaga\n","times":{"04":8},"joins":{"Sky":1,"microbe":1},"totallines":8,"monocount":0,"lastvisited":{"Parts:":1,"microbe":1,"Sky":1},"word_times":{"microbe":[9],"Sky":[1]},"line_times":{"Sky":[1],"microbe":[3]},"parsedlines":8,"lengths":{"Sky":11,"microbe":36},"day_lines":[null,8]}
{"sayings":{"microbe":["Hello"],"Sky":[";algkagkaga"]},"actionlines":{"microbe":["[04:33:53] * microbe is doing just a test\n"]}}
```